# xstream serialize heap space

Tags: java, xml, xstream, filewriter

I am using xstream to serialize an object into xml as a file. The object that I want to serialize is very large and consists of a quite complicated tree-structure. For this I am using the following code:

```
    XStream xStream = new XStream();

    xStream.omitField(Stat.class, "sources");
    String XMLFilename = "XML-" + dateString + ".xml";

    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

    Writer writer = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(currentWorkPath+XMLFilename);
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        xStream.toXML(ss, writer);

    } catch (Exception exp) {
        log.error(null, exp);
    } finally {
        writer = null;
        outputStream = null;
    }
```

The code works fine, but I get out of memory error java heap space when serializing very large objects. Is there some way to prevent this? Is it possible to build the xml on the fly, as the object is growing?

Or maybe some other xml serializing library?

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.ObjectIdDictionary.associateId(ObjectIdDictionary.java:91)
```

Thanks,
James Ford

Comment: It should be writing the object as it navigates the object to be serilaized. It needs to record every object in the structure in case of repeated references, but unless you have a very large numebr of objects, this shouldn't be significant.  I suspect the simplest thing you can do is increase the maximum heap size.

Comment: We need an example of the XML and the associated java files...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Xpp3 library on classpath (ex. on server)? XStream on Java 5 and lower without Xpp3 (or other similar library) on classpath uses the DOM driver. Without any example I can only this suspecting.